# Building Select Statement

Tags: vbscript

The following SELECT statement works fine when using radio buttons on the corresponding query form, but errors-out when I change the radios to checkboxes and I execute the query with 2 or more checkboxes selected. Any suggestions as what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
strSelect = "SELECT * FROM qryMyQuery WHERE"
Select Case strOption
Case "Name" 
  strSelect = strSelect & " Name='" & UCase(strName) & "'"

Case "Location" 
  strSelect = strSelect & " Location='" & UCase(strLocation) & "'"

Case "Type"
  strSelect = strSelect & " Type='" & UCase(strType) & "'"

Case "Season"
  strSelect = strSelect & " Season='" & UCase(strSeason) & "'"

Case "Duration"
  strSelect = strSelect & " Duration='" & UCase(strDuration) & "'"

Case "Year"
  strSelect = strSelect & " Year='" & UCase(strYear) & "'"

End Select
```

The error occurs at line 111 shortly after the SELECT statement and right after I make the DB connection.

> Line 111: 
>       Set RS = dB.Execute(strSelect)

The error is as follows:

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in WHERE clause.
 /query2.asp, line 111

Here's the simplified query form...

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>

<%

' *** Dim the variables ***
Dim strName
Dim strLocation
Dim strType
Dim strSeason
Dim strYear
Dim strDuration
Dim strSubmit
Dim DB
Dim strInsert
Dim seloption

' *** Open the database ***
Set DB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DB.ConnectionTimeout=60
DB.Open "XXXX"

%>

<FORM ACTION="query2.asp" METHOD="get">

<B>Object Name:</B>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="seloption" VALUE="Name" CHECKED>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME=Name>

<B>Location/Region:</B>
     <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="seloption" VALUE="Location">
     <SELECT size=1 name=Location>
     <option name="Location" value="AAA">AAA</option>
     <option name="Location" value="BBB">BBB</option>
      </select>

<B>Season:</B>
     <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="seloption" VALUE="Season">
     <SELECT size=1 name=Season>
     <option name="Season" value="Summer">Summer</option>
      <option name="Season" value="Fall">Fall</option>
      </select>

    <B>Type:</B>
    <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="seloption" VALUE="Type">
     <SELECT size=1 name=Type>
      <option name="Type" value="CCC">CCC</option>
      <option name="Type" value="DDD">DDD</option>
     </select>  

<B>Year:</B>
  <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="seloption" VALUE="Yr">
    <SELECT size=1 name=Yr>
    <option name="Year" value="2015">2015</option>
    <option name="Year" value="2014">2014</option>
    <option name="Year" value="various">various</option>
    </select>

<B>Duration:</B>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="seloption" VALUE="Duration">
    <SELECT size=1 name=Duration>
    <option name="Duration" value="1 day">1 day</option>
    <option name="Duration" value="2 days">2 days</option>
    <option name="Duration" value="na">n/a</option>
    </select>

     <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit Query">
     <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Show All" NAME="btnAll">
     <INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Clear Form">

</FORM>

<%
dB.Close
%>
```

Comment: Is your *Year* stored as a string? i.e. Do you need to wrap the year criteria in quotes?

Comment: Can you print the query that produces this error?

Comment: The column in the table is named Year with numeric values (ie. 2010, 2011 etc).  That being said, I seem to recall that the word Year is reserved in MS Access and should not be used?

Comment: The query form is as follows - sorry for the length...

Comment: Sorry, too many characters to paste here.  Any suggestions for how to post the query form?

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30380649/edit) to append any additional data.

Comment: On a related topic, shouldn't those INPUT elements be [type=RADIO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms535838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and *not* type=CHECKBOX? You would only ever want one of them selected. A type=CHECKBOX generally returns CHECKED or TRUE.

Comment: I currently have it configured for RADIO but was exploring using CHECKBOX so that I could query against multiple criteria versus just one. As stated previously, with RADIO the query returns the desired results, but I get an error if after I replace the RADIOs with CHECKBOXes and re-run the query with at least 2 or more of the checkboxes selected.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you have some reserved words used as field names that need square brackets in order that they are properly interpreted as fields of the stored **qryMyQuery** query.

```
strSelect = "SELECT * FROM qryMyQuery WHERE"
Select Case strOption
    Case "Name" 
      strSelect = strSelect & " [Name]='" & UCase(strName) & "'"
    Case "Location" 
      strSelect = strSelect & " Location='" & UCase(strLocation) & "'"
    Case "Type"
      strSelect = strSelect & " [Type]='" & UCase(strType) & "'"
    Case "Season"
      strSelect = strSelect & " Season='" & UCase(strSeason) & "'"
    Case "Duration"
      strSelect = strSelect & " Duration='" & UCase(strDuration) & "'"
    Case "Year"
      strSelect = strSelect & " [Year]=" & strYear
End Select
```

Note that I've interpreted the **[YEAR]** field as a number.

Comment: Thanks.  I have added the square brackets as suggested and changed the column name and references in the code from Year to simply Yr.  Same error unfortunately.

Comment: I tend to stick with T-SQL's Views and Tables but I do know that Access stored queries are better accessed with [QueryDef object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177500%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (more at [DAO Querydef: Using Querydefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa293464(v=vs.60).aspx)). Are you getting anything with a straight SELECT statement and no filter? Can you output the concatenated SELECT statement for examination before sending it to the db engine?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect one of your variable is feeded directly from html checkboxes am I right ?

In this case if you are selecting many checkboxes with the same name you will end up with a value like `strYear = "2014, 2015, 2016"` because values of checkboxes with the same name are joined together when you read the request, this will fail to evaluate to an integer in the sql query.

But the best way to debug the query is to print the sql syntax by just replacing your `Set RS = dB.Execute(strSelect)` line with `Response.Write strSelect`.

*UPDATE*

Based on your comments I think i know what is happening, when you do `strOption = Request.QueryString("seloption")`, because many inputs have this name, you get a value like `strOption = "Location, Type, Year"`, so your code does not enter any of the select cases and your query end up to only `SELECT * FROM qryMyQuery WHERE`, that would explain the error message you get.

If you allow the user to check many options you will have to refactorize your Select Case anyway, you can keep the same name for checkboxes but just loop through the request value like this:

```
strSelect = "SELECT * FROM qryMyQuery"
bolFirst = True
For Each strOption In Split(Request.QueryString("seloption"), ", ")

    If bolFirst Then
        strSelect = strSelect & " WHERE"
        bolFirst = False
    Else
        strSelect = strSelect & " AND"
    End If

    Select Case strOption
        Case "Name" 
          strSelect = strSelect & " Name='" & UCase(strName) & "'"

        Case "Location" 
          strSelect = strSelect & " Location='" & UCase(strLocation) & "'"

        Case "Type"
          strSelect = strSelect & " Type='" & UCase(strType) & "'"

        Case "Season"
          strSelect = strSelect & " Season='" & UCase(strSeason) & "'"

        Case "Duration"
          strSelect = strSelect & " Duration='" & UCase(strDuration) & "'"

        Case "Year"
          strSelect = strSelect & " Year='" & UCase(strYear) & "'"

    End Select 
Next
```

Other things to consider:

- You would find very useful to use a debugger to trace your code, you
  would   find the problems much more easily
- Consider to use [ADO parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681010(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of concatenating the
  value in the sql query string to prevent [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: This is not true in your code snipnet they all have name="seloption"

Comment: Ah, yes...good point.  I think you're on to something here.  I can change each CHECKBOX to use uniqu names, but then that would break the SELECT statement above (Select Case strOption) because I have the following defined strOption = Request.QueryString("seloption")

Comment: I responded to your answer with the code as it appears now and my observations. thanks!

Comment: Jonathan, upon closer inspection it appears that I had omitted several double quotes for values within the SELECT tags of the form. Such as: <SELECT size="1" name="Location">.  After correcting this, the query works as expected.  thanks again!